# Android NDK in Adroid Studio 2.1 Preview 5 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, disk-usage, android-studio

In **project structure** there is a download NDK link that starts the DL

I get error "No space left on disk"

I know more than enough space is on the drive.

Comment: Where are you going to save Android NDK? which address?

Comment: It never prompted me for a location, or is that what that empty textbox was for... Hmmm brb

Comment: @Mahdi a where is it normally pathed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to **File > Project Structure** and from the left panel select **SDK Location** as in the bottom image. There you can see or change the location of your SDK/NDK.

[image]